# Having issues with a MySQL Join that needs to meet multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `rooms` and `rooms facilities` and I have to select the rooms with desired facilities.

If I select a room with one facility (facility with id=4 - id_fu - ). using the following query Everything it's ok:

```
SELECT u.* FROM rooms u 
JOIN facilities_r fu 
ON fu.id_uc = u.id_uc 
    AND fu.id_fu = '4' 
WHERE 1 
    AND vizibility='1' 
GROUP BY id_uc 
ORDER BY u_premium desc, id_uc DESC
```

But if I want to select the room with more facilities, let's say facilities with id=4, and id=3 ..using the following query it doesn't work:

```
SELECT u.* FROM room u 
JOIN facilities_r fu 
ON fu.id_uc=u.id_uc 
    AND fu.id_fu = '4' 
    AND fu.id_fu = '3' 
WHERE 1 
    AND vizibility = '1' 
GROUP BY id_uc 
ORDER BY u_premium DESC, id_uc DESC
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure up how to put the condition.

Comment: No facility can be 3 and 4 at the same time. Use OR instead of AND

Answer (score 89):

You can group conditions with parentheses. When you are checking if a field is equal to another, you want to use `OR`. For example `WHERE a='1' AND (b='123' OR b='234')`.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM rooms AS u
JOIN facilities_r AS fu
ON fu.id_uc = u.id_uc AND (fu.id_fu='4' OR fu.id_fu='3')
WHERE vizibility='1'
GROUP BY id_uc
ORDER BY u_premium desc, id_uc desc
```

Comment: What if you want to ensure both conditions are met (ie: a room that has both those facilities). You can `COUNT(*)` the grouped row (in this case you would ensure that the `COUNT(*) = 2`. Is there a preferred way?

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT 
    u . *
FROM
    room u
        JOIN
    facilities_r fu ON fu.id_uc = u.id_uc
        AND (fu.id_fu = '4' OR fu.id_fu = '3')
WHERE
    1 and vizibility = '1'
GROUP BY id_uc
ORDER BY u_premium desc , id_uc desc
```

You must use OR here, not AND.

Since id_fu cannot be equal to 4 and 3, both at once.

Comment: Yes it it works with or but it's not correct... The lines from facilities_r are id_f_unit  id_uc  id_fu
           18            4    4
     17            4    3   so i need to select them...

Comment: Fine, in that case also you should use OR only. To select records which have x=5,6,7 you must write x=5 OR x=6 OR x=7

Comment: Thanks for help...I tried wit sub queries and it seems to work  select u.* from rooms u JOIN facilities_r fu on fu.id_uc=u.id_uc and 4 in (SELECT id_fu from facilities_r fu where fu.id_uc=u.id_uc) and 3 in (SELECT id_fu from facilities_r fu where fu.id_uc=u.id_uc) where 1 and vizibilitate='1' group by id_uc order by u_premium desc, id_uc desc but this will probably take more time to be executed than the first one...but it works:)

Answer (score 8):

If you join the facilities table twice you will get what you are after:

```
select u.* 
from room u 
  JOIN facilities_r fu1 on fu1.id_uc = u.id_uc and fu1.id_fu = '4'
  JOIN facilities_r fu2 on fu2.id_uc = u.id_uc and fu2.id_fu = '3' 
where 1 and vizibility='1' 
group by id_uc 
order by u_premium desc, id_uc desc
```

Answer (score 4):

also this should work (not tested):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM room u 
JOIN facilities_r fu ON fu.id_uc = u.id_uc AND u.id_fu IN(4,3)
WHERE 1 AND vizibility = 1 
GROUP BY id_uc 
ORDER BY u_premium desc , id_uc desc
```

If `u.id_fu` is a numeric field then you can remove the `'` around them.
The same for `vizibility`. Only if the field is a text field (data type char, varchar or one of the text-datatype e.g. longtext) then the value has to be enclosed by `'` or even `"`.

Also I and Oracle too recommend to enclose table and field names in backticks.
So you won't get into trouble if a field name contains a keyword.