# tableau join multiple tables ORing on single column

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have following tables: `Product` and  `ProductEvent`. Some of the relevant columns of `Product` table are `SocialID, MarketID, LocalID`. These three columns have numbers that corresponds to one column called `EventID` in `ProductEvent`.

Here is my question: is there a better way to join these tables where I do not have to make 3 separate joins all pointing to match `EventID`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018550/mysql-join-with-multiple-conditions):

```
select *
from Product P join ProductEvent PE
on (PE.EventID = P.SocialID or PE.EventID = P.MarketID or PE.EventID = P.LocalID)
```